# Can I customise the look of Stormpath's login screen?

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

Stormpath's login view https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/product.html#disable-the-built-in-views doesn't match the styling of the rest of my app. Can I customise the look, either by providing my own styling or replacing the view completely?

I've tried to find documentation on this but all I've been able to find out is that [StormPath allows disabling the built in views](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/product.html#disable-the-built-in-views).

Answer (score 3):

I literally just found the official docs on [Customising the Built-in Views](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/product.html#the-most-basic-view) 30 seconds after writing that question.

Comment: @rdegges Will do, I have to wait till tomorrow though, since it's my own answer.